# Set rowspan value base on the next column

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a table using a DOM, but i'm having a trouble with this arrangement of the data.

I have an array..

```
let myData = [
        {
            options: "Option 1",
            details: [
                {
                    type: "Big Letters",
                    value: [
                        {name: "A"},
                        {name: "B"},
                        {name: "C"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    type: "Small Letters",
                    value: [
                        {name: "a"},
                        {name: "b"},
                        {name: "c"}
                    ]
                },
                //Other codes here...
            ]
        },
            {
                options: "Option 2",
                details: [
                {
                    type: "Numbers",
                    value: [
                        {name: 1},
                        {name: 2},
                        {name: 3},
                        {name: 4},
                        {name: 5}
                    ]
                },
                //Other codes here...
            ]
        },
        //Other codes here...
    ];
```

Then i create a loop using forEach function and show the output using innerHTML. But the arrangement of data was messy. So i try to set up the `rowspan` but still messy(It seems their is lacking on my codes.

My fuction is...

```
let html ="<table border='1'>";
    html +=`
    <tr> 
        <th>Options</th>
        <th>Types</th>
        <th>Values</th>
    </tr>`;
    myData.forEach((item) => {
        html += "<tr>";
        html += `<td rowspan="${item.details.length}">${item.options}<td>`;
        item.details.forEach((item2) => {
            html += `<td rowspan="${item2.value.length}">${item2.type}</td>`
            item2.value.forEach((item3) => {
                html += `<td>${item3.name}</td>`
                html += "</tr>";
            })
        })
    })
    html += "</table>";
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Here is my current output:

[image]

I would like my table look like this.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this output?

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only add each cell with an increased `rowspan` to the first row in which it should be shown.

Here is an example:

```js
let myData=[{options:"Option 1",details:[{type:"Big Letters",value:[{name:"A"},{name:"B"},{name:"C"}]},{type:"Small Letters",value:[{name:"a"},{name:"b"},{name:"c"}]}]},{options:"Option 2",details:[{type:"Numbers",value:[{name:1},{name:2},{name:3},{name:4},{name:5}]},]},];

const makeCell = (text, type = 'td') => Object.assign(document.createElement(type), {textContent: text});
const table = document.createElement('table');
table.border = 1;
const thRow = document.createElement('tr');
thRow.append(...['Options', 'Types', 'Values'].map(x => makeCell(x, 'th')));
table.append(thRow);
for (const data of myData) {
  const optionCell = makeCell(data.options);
  optionCell.rowSpan = data.details.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.value.length, 0);
  let i = 0;
  for (const detail of data.details) {
    const typeCell = makeCell(detail.type);
    typeCell.rowSpan = detail.value.length;
    for (const { name } of detail.value) {
      const row = document.createElement('tr');
      row.append(...[optionCell, typeCell, makeCell(name)].slice(i));
      table.append(row);
      i = 2;
    }
    i = 1;
  }
}
document.body.append(table);
```